# context post async exception

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Using bot simulator :

Have this code in MessagesController :

```
 await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootLuisDialog());
```

In RootLuisDialog :

```
        [LuisIntent("")]
        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            string message = $"Sorry, I did not understand '{result.Query}'. Type 'help' if you need assistance.";

            await context.PostAsync(message);

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
```

This makes an Exception :

> {"Type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity' in Assembly
>   'Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable."}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HResult: -2146233076
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: null
>       Message: "Type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity' in Assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable."
>       Source: "mscorlib"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean
>   fCheck)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream,  Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean
>   fCheck)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.FormatterStore`1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore<T>.Save(T
>   item)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.ErrorResilientStore`1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore.Save(T
>   item)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.FactoryStore`1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore<T>.Save(T
>   item)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDial
>   ogTask.
>   d__5`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.Co mpilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.Throw ForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   MessengerBot.MessagesController.d__1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\myapp\MessagesController.cs:line 60"
>       TargetSite: {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] InternalGetSerializableMembers(System.RuntimeType)}

I am not pretty sure that i understand what exception here is ... 
some help ?

Edit : I solved the problem with new constructor for rootluisdialog with parameter - activity.

await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootLuisDialog(activity));
and then in the RootLuisDialog i have this :

```
 Activity activity;
public RootLuisDialog(Activity activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;

        }
```

Comment: Please, delete the question if the problem was already solved

Comment: Though the solution you are applying doesn't sound like the right one

Comment: Yes. It isn't. Any idea ?

Comment: The answer below looks accurate. Not sure why you are trying to hold a reference on the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Activity` class isn't serialisable, which is the error you're seeing. All public or protected properties in the `LuisDialog` need to be serialisable so that they can be stored as contexts between responses.

Assuming your Dialog class is inheriting from `LuisDialog` then this should already be taking care of grabbing the activity from the intent - in general you'd be working with the context and the result from LUIS rather than the activity directly (as you would if you were creating a straight up `IDialog` implementation).

Passing it in from the controller also won't do what you expect as it won't be included on subsequent calls in the conversation.

Comment: So how to make this Activity class serialized ?

Comment: You can't really - what are you trying to do with the activity that you can't do with the context and LuisResult?

Comment: I am trying to forward to another dialog.

Comment: So, i am calling directly that LuisDialog. And it throws an exception. How can e resolve this ?